# ESP8266-05 always return +CWJAP:4 on connection to any Wi-Fi network

Tags: networking, arduino, iot, esp8266, esp8266wifi

I am a novice with ESP8266. I have an ESP-05 module connected to my PC USB through CH340 com-port adapter.

I was able to list all networks with AT+CWLAP, but when I put the command to connect to, it shows me a CWJAP:4 error. I tried my home network, the network in my office, and the Wi-Fi network created by my Android phone. The same result always...

```
AT+GMRAT version:1.3.0.0(Jul 14 2016 18:54:01)
SDK version:2.0.0(5a875ba)
v1.0.0.3
Mar 13 2018 09:35:47
OK
```

```
AT+CWMODE=1
OK
```

```
AT+CWLAP+CWLAP:(3,"TheSecretChamber",-76,"f0:79:59:d3:00:44",13,68,0)
+CWLAP:(4,"Ufanet_70",-90,"04:5e:a4:76:0d:cf",3,50,0)
+CWLAP:(3,"AndroidAP",-49,"84:98:66:ce:a6:ed",6,66,0)

OK
```

```
AT+CWJAP="TheSecretChamber","mypasswordhere"+CWJAP:4

FAIL
```

The password is 100% valid (I've tried to put the wrong password, in this case, it returns CWJAP:3 as required).

What can be a reason?? Thanks.

Comment: did you try it without bssid?

Comment: @Juraj Yes, I did. Sorry wrong example, I should use one without bssid. But I tried with and without.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself. It looks like the USB port I used initially has not enough power or it's broken somehow. The network list command is working, but its USB power was not enough to handle transmitting.

I just tried another USB port and it works well.

Thanks all.